# install R on a server which cannot get access to internet

Tags: r, window, system-administration

I need to install R on a windows server which does not allow me to get access outside network, i.e., internet. Can I install that as follows: I install the R as well as needed package on another machine, and copy the whole folder to that server. Will this approach work?

Comment: Why not just put the installer onto a flash drive and install from that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will.  R happily runs off a usb stick, you could use that to copy your installation over.

See here for mre:

- [Running R on a USB drive](http://personal.bgsu.edu/~mrizzo/Rmisc/usbR.htm)
- [R on Windows FAQ on running R off USB drive](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Can-I-run-R-from-a-CD-or-USB-drive_003f)

Copying off an existing machine may make assumptions about registry entries etc. This approach seems safer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:  Buy the new iPhone5, purchase the Tethering Data Plan,  connect your new custom mini-iPhone -to -USB cable to your server, and you've got an internet connection!

Comment: And to you humor-impaired down-voters: I *know* Dirk's answer is the correct one!